# Axis environment problem: how to determine a domain in which x and y axes are to be drawn?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, graphs

Let's suppose that I want to put a neat graph of the sinus function in my document. Its source code is:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\begin{axis}[
xmin=-11, xmax=11,
ymin=-1.2, ymax=1.2,
grid=both,
axis lines=middle,
minor tick num=9,
axis line style={latex-latex},
ticklabel style={font=\tiny},
axis equal
]

\addplot[line width=0.7pt, blue, samples=500][domain=-11:11]{sin((x*180)/pi)};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

And it produces the following result:

[image]

So far so good. But let's say I want to cram my graph into a single page nicely, without it taking too much space. For this reason, I want to "cut" y axis on both sides, in other words, I want to force the graph to only be rendered on an interval (a,b) (on y axis) without changing the aspect ratio of the graph or its size.

For this purpose, I wrote `ymin=-1.2, ymax=1.2`, as you can see in my MWE. But this has no effect on the graph! Why? I searched the internet for a solution to my problem for a long time, but found none.

Please, provide me a technique with which I will be able to achieve this task. This goes for limiting the interval on which the whole axis is rendered for **x axis as well**, not just y axis (which won't be used in this case, but could definitely be useful in my future endeavours). Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason `ymin`/`ymax` doesn't work is I think that you have `axis equal`, and you haven't changed the width/height of the axis, so the default size is used.

If you remove `axis equal` the y-limits will apply, but the x and y unit vectors will not be equal, which you want, if I understand correctly.

So instead try setting the size, by adding something like `width=10cm,height=4cm` to the `axis options`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xmin=-11, xmax=11,
ymin=-1.2, ymax=1.2,
width=10cm,height=4cm,
grid=both,
axis lines=middle,
minor x tick num=9,
minor y tick num=2,
axis line style={latex-latex},
ticklabel style={font=\tiny},
axis equal
]

\addplot[line width=0.7pt, blue, samples=500, domain=-11:11]{sin((x*180)/pi)};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Great solution. How do I preserve my minor grid count though?

Comment: @GregorPerčič As mentioned in a comment in my code, I changed the minor grid count. Just change it back, or to a more suitable number (as in nidhin's answer, which I think is better than mine). I changed it because it was, to my eyes, far too dense.

Comment: No no, I find the squeezed lines horrible as well. What I meant so say is how do I preserve the equal spacing of both vertical and horizontal lines of the grid. I'd like to have my grid exactly the same way it is in my provided picture.

Comment: @GregorPerčič `minor x tick num=8,
minor y tick num=2,`?

Comment: Thank you! I'm embarrassed that I didn't figure it out sooner! I just had to look at your code (at first I didn't notice the "x" subargument). `minor x tick num=9, minor y tick num=1,` will do for me.

Answer (score 3):

Use `axis equal image` instead of `axis equal`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\begin{axis}[
xmin=-11, xmax=11,
ymin=-2, ymax=2,
grid=both,
axis lines=middle,
minor x tick num=9,
minor y tick num=1,
axis line style={latex-latex},
ticklabel style={font=\tiny},
axis equal image
]
\addplot[line width=0.7pt, blue, samples=500][domain=-11:11]{sin((x*180)/pi)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But how do I keep the "grid ratio" equal? The minor grid count on y axis is not spaced in the same way as on x axis. I'd like them to be the same.

Comment: @GregorPerčič One way is to adjust the `minor tick num`s. See edited answer.

Comment: I've already discussed this solution under Torbjørn's answer. Thank you nonetheless!